# How to get height of text, that's gonna be viewed by UILabel object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, height, row

I need to get height of text, that's gonna be viewed by UILabel object, so I can set height of  row in table. Method `fontWithSize:` is depracated in iOS 7 and when I use `sizeWithAttributes:` I get only size of one line, not the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your label with text and all of the required properties, after that call:

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

Now you can read the hight from

```
float height = CGRectGetMaxY(label.frame);
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 use this method to get dynamic size of an string

`- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context`

To get multiple line make sure set numberOfLines for your label

```
labelObj.numberOfLines = 0;
```